# Should math and mathematics be tag synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

There are two tags, [math](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) and [mathematics](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mathematics), which I believe should be made synonyms of each other.

On another note, they do not have usage guidelines. My assumption would be that a question tagged with `math` can be:

- a question about a specific formula
- a question requesting a mathematical answer (as opposed to intuitive)

Any other idea?

Comment: I created the synonym suggestion. you may vote on it now

Comment: Fantastic, thank you!